# Fixing Night Shift Perpetually Enabled With "Unsupported" (Non-Apple/LG) External Monitors Under macOS 10.12.4 - 10.13.6

Tags: display, macos, night-shift

***Notice:*** ***After several years I feel the need to say this. I originally wrote this as a guide for fixing a specific issue that occurred on builds of macOS shortly after Night Shift was introduced as a feature. The issue occurred because of a known glitch for handling enabling of Night Shift at installation time when  upgrading a <10.12.4 macOS installation to 10.12.4 - 10.13.6 builds. Specifically this issue only occurred for people who were not using either an Apple monitor or the one model of LG monitor Apple "supported" at that time. Coinciding with their statement that they would "not support" other models of monitor for external displays on Macs with embedded displays (due to the way display drivers were handled at the time this also effected all Hackintosh users), Apple included code in macOS that would detect a monitor's brand and model by EDID and disable the Night Shift pane in settings. This led to a situation where the upgrade would enable Night Shift and the user would be left unable to disable it. The topic of this post has nothing to do with damaged cables, improperly seated cables, or an attempt to get the equivalent of Night Shift functionality on non-Apple/LG external displays. It is not a general thread for Night Shift as a feature and is intended to act as a guide to fix a known technical issue/incompatibility in a specific combination of macOS builds and monitors. I humbly request that users stop filling up the answers thread and muddying the waters with unrelated answers to unrelated Night Shift issues. Thank you. -OP***

If you use an external monitor for your Mac of any shape or size and recently updated to macOS Sierra 10.12.4, chances are you've had some trouble with Night Shift.

Common issues include:

- the inability to configure Night Shift from your external monitor
- Night Shift being impossible to disable (as a result of the former)
- a substantial loss of colour quality (as a result of both of the former happening at once on some connection or screen types, most commonly DVI-D to VGA, DisplayPort, and LCD screens of all kinds.)

How do you get past these issues? Is there a way to enable access to the Night Shift pane on any display?

Comment: This is a known issue on Displaylink monitors, please vote for this issue here: https://support.displaylink.com/forums/287786-displaylink-feature-suggestions/suggestions/18840574-support-night-shift-and-f-lux-for-mac-os

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After two days of searching, I've found a solution that allows users to get past the Night Shift incompatibility issues with external monitors. This solution helps to enable access to Night Shift on any display.

1. Connect your external monitor, disable your internal monitor, and make sure your external monitor is set as the default.
2. **Download required files.** You will need two programs (and a third optional) to proceed. The first is FixEDID, which can be found here: [FixEDID](https://github.com/andyvand/FixEDID_Devel/archive/master.zip), the second is DarwinDumper and can be found here: [DarwinDumper](https://bitbucket.org/blackosx/darwindumper/downloads/DarwinDumper_v2.9.9.2.zip), and the final (optional) one is KextWizard, found here: [KextWizard](http://wizards.osxlatitude.com/kext/download.html)
3. Open FixEDID, wait for the fields to auto-load, and minimize FixEDID, do not close it.
4. Open DarwinDumper, click *Deselect All*, check the EDID box, and click *Run*. You will be prompted for your password, and the dump directory will auto-open when it is done. Close DarwinDumper, and copy *EDID.bin* to your desktop.
5. Unminimize FixEDID, click *Open EDID Binary File*, select your *EDID.bin*. Now in the drop down menu under that button choose the internal monitor for your model of Mac (this will usually be the first option), and click the *Make* button. You should have a few new files now, but you can ignore all of them except *DisplayMergeNub.kext*, which you will need.
6. (*Kext Wizard Version*) Open Kext Wizard, click the *Installation* tab, click *Browse*, choose *DisplayMergeNub.kext*, and click *Install*. You will be asked for your password. Once it has finished reboot your Mac.
7. (*Manual Installation*) Open Terminal.app and run the following command `sudo mv $(whoami)/Desktop/DisplayMergeNub.kext /System/Library/Extensions/ && sudo reboot`. You will be asked for your password, and your Mac will automatically reboot as soon as the operation finishes.
8. Upon rebooting you can go to Apple > About This Mac and under the Displays tab you will find your Mac now considers your external monitor to be your internal monitor, as a result Night Shift should not be auto enabled anymore, and you can now access the Night Shift preference pane from Settings.

***A Quick Note***

For those who want to reverse this process so that your external monitor is no longer considered a built-in display by your Mac, you can simply run the command `sudo rm /System/Library/Extensions/DisplayMergeNub.kext && sudo reboot`.

As with the previous command this will ask for your password, and automatically reboot your Mac after the process is finished.

***UPDATE: 01/04/2019*** *As of later versions of macOS 10.13 and all versions of 10.14 external displays are being recognized natively when they are the only connected display. Thus this information should be considered deprecated except to those using a **secondary** external display, or those running macOS versions 10.12.4-10.13.4*

Answer (score 77):

Unplug the cable and insert it again.

It works for me.

**Update for Catalina (macOS 10.15)**: For secondary monitors, you may have to unplug primary monitor, so that the secondary monitor is the primary monitor. (Doing this once should be enough)

by @Michael_Scharf

Comment: Oddly enough this worked but only when I unplugged the end connected to my external monitor. When I unplugged the end connected to the Mackbook Pro it didn't have an effect.

Answer (score 20):

For me the following worked:

- disable night shift
- disconnect external display
- reconnect external display
- enable night shift

Comment: Hi, this post was made in regard to an issue that would cause users to be ***unable*** to disable Night Shift because of the settings pane for it being disabled due to macOS recognizing the monitor as "unsupported". In these cases the user would not be able to access Night Shift settings on the embedded monitor either. Please either revise this answer to denote what you were fixing, or migrate it to a more related issue's thread.

Answer (score 7):

After trying above solutions without success, I found the "true tone" setting in "display settings" of "system preferences", unchecked it, and external monitor became normal white again. Just in case it may help someone. I have an LG 4k with a USB-C cable.

Comment: Hi Hugues, thanks for your comment as it is likely to help people who came to this thread regarding issues with Apple's officially "supported" monitors. However, I would like to note that the LG 4k series was one of the few officially "supported" monitors by Apple, and this thread was intended to address incompatibility with 3rd party "unsupported" monitors.

Answer (score 6):

Another option is to download [Flux](https://justgetflux.com/). It is an alternative to NightShift, and reliably works on both internal and external monitors. It acts as a replacement to NightShift, so should not be run together.

Comment: Flux conflicts with Night Shift and causes additional issues, and installing it would in fact only make the situation worse (I tried, it did.). It should also be noted that Flux is in no way capable of fixing system level incompatibilities between Night Shift and the macOS external display handler. This is neither a solution to the main problem (inability to access or change Night Shift settings from an external monitor) nor the main symptoms (Night Shift being perpetually enabled on external monitors, or scheduling not working on internal monitors on a Mac using external display).

Comment: I definitely do not recommend Flux. Just use the in-built Night Shift one will do.

Comment: I use Flux on Windows and never had any issues, haven't had a BSOD in years. On my work MacBook I've experienced all kinds of idiotic issues, including reboots when waking the laptop from sleep, and now this NightShift issue.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was switching cables. At first I was using a USB-C to HDMI adapter. When I changed the plug to connect the monitor with my MacBook without the adapter it started to work without any issues.

Answer (score 1):

For me it works when I change the resolution (and change it back to the initial value afterwards again).

Answer (score 1):

I have multiple monitors and this happens sometimes, with one or more but not all monitors stuck in Night Shift.

What worked today, inspired by earlier answers to this question: System Preferences → Displays → Arrangement, drag menu bar from one monitor to another to change primary display, then drag it back to restore things to how they were.

Answer (score 1):

## if anyone is looking for a very simple solution...

It is not Night Shift, but...

```
brew install redshift
```

does the job well enough (for me anyway on this 2011 MacMini 5,1 with macOS Mojave)

not sure how it does on dual monitors, however

Comment: This is awesome!

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 UHD 4K 27" LG 27UD88-W USB-C monitors hooked up to my 2017 MacBook Pro w/ Touch Bar via a single Thunderbolt 3 cable. This is achieved by way of an Elgato Thunderbolt 3 dock. (The monitors did not have enough power for the laptop alone and wouldn't offer a reliable single-cable solution.)

I initially had issues with one of the two monitors being recognized reliably.  It was always the one connected to the dock via USB-C. (The other connected via DisplayPort.) I figured this was probably some driver issue.

I installed their DualController and OnScreenControl  Mac OS software. Both installers required a reboot. The reboot did seem to help. However, I'm not sure if it was the software, the reboot, or both that ultimately fixed my issue with Night Shift failing on both of the monitors. I had already rebooted the system after introducing the Elgato Dock the day before.

The moral being, I'd suggest seeking out any software packages offered by the monitor manufacturer just in case they bundle drivers with them.

Answer (score 0):

make sure to check your monitor display profile.

displays > color > display profile

in my case i found that the profile was stuck on a Flux scheme (i used this previously) and it seemed like night shift was not going away. once i selected my monitor's profile the issue went away