# Cannot enable Night Shift on macOS high sierra 10.13.3

Tags: error, night-shift

Always when i try to turn on night shift nothing changes and i can see following error messages in the logs:

```
ColorSync: ColorSyncProfileCreateWithDisplayID failed to get profile for kColorSyncDisplayDeviceClass
```

Does anyone else have this problem or knows how to fix it?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you are using external monitor(s), the answer to this [AskDifferent question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/278789/fixing-night-shift-incompatibility-with-external-monitors) may provide a clue or two.

Comment: Try using the Colorsync application first aid to repair and verify the profile.

Comment: thanks for the tips. But im not using external monitors. And there are no errors found when i try to repair or to verify.