# Does macOS Mojave support NightShift on external monitors?

Tags: macos, display, sleep-wake, mojave, night-shift

After upgrading to [Mojave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Mojave), I could have sworn I saw [Night Shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Night_Shift_(software)) kick-in on my external [4K](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4K_resolution) [BenQ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BenQ) monitor. But no more.

Did I dream that? Or is Mojave supposed to be capable of supporting Night Shift on external displays? If so, might it stop working because of sleeping/waking and/or attaching/detaching the monitor?

Answer (score 5):

Night Shift is working on external monitors in Mojave.

Sometimes Night Shift deactivates itself on the external display when you wake the system from sleep. (Maybe a Bug?)

Just reactivate it manually.

1. If Night Shift is off, go to the Night Shift tab in System
   Preferences>Display and check the box labelled Turn on until
   tomorrow.
2. If Night Shift is on, click on the Schedule menu in the Night shift
   tab and choose  ‘Off.’
3. Use the color temperature slider in the same window to control the
   degree to which colors change when Night Switch is turned on or off.

Comment: Unfortunately, that does not work with my MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Late 2013) with NVIDIA GeForce GT 750M 2 GB running macOS Mojave 10.14.4. NightShift can be enabled/disabled as you described, but only affects the built-in display. The external BenQ 4K monitor does not change its bright white coloring.