# Using night shift/f.lux on external monitors Mac OS 10.15

Tags: macos, display, night-shift

I’m having an issue using Night Shift, f.lux, or any blue light filter application on 2 of the 3 external monitors I have hooked up to my MacBook Pro via a Dell docking station. This is my hardware:

- MacBook Pro 2019
- Dell D6000 dock
- Dell 24 in monitor
- Dell 24 in monitor
- LG 34 in monitor

I’ve tried reseating cables, reinstalling display link drivers, and downloading other blue light filter applications like f.lux.

Comment: What is the issue you are having? Do some monitors change color but not others? Do you get the same behaviour with f.lux and Night Shift?

Comment: f.lux and Night Shift are Blue Light filters.

Comment: @JasonSalaz Ever get this figured out? I'm having a similar problem: MacBook Pro 2021, Plugable USB-C docking station, and Night Shift working on only 1 of 3 external monitors. All three of my monitors are the same model and have the same EDID information, so my best guess for why they won't work with Night Shift is [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/410933), but I don't have a solution.

Comment: I didn’t ask the question, I just edited it to pretty up the formatting. And then replied to the other comment because I knew the context.

Comment: Oops, sorry. For posterity, here is the reply I got from Pluggable (tl;dr it's an issue with Display link):

_Apple's Night Shift mode is not supported on the DisplayLink controlled "Display 2" and "Display 3" output ports.
 
This is a limitation of the DisplayLink USB Graphics Technology and we call this out in our website's compatibility section ( https://plugable.com/products/ud-6950pdz#nav-compatibility )._

Comment: _The docking station uses two graphics technologies to support up to three external displays, the "Display 1" outputs are directly controlled by the computer's built-in graphics controller and support Night Shift and other color calibration technologies just like any directly connected external display.  The "Display 2" and "Display 3" outputs are controlled by the DisplayLink Manager App and hardware int he docking station.  No to be confused with "DisplayPort" the port type, DisplayLink is a company that manufactures USB Graphics Chipsets and the software to control them._

Comment: _To expand the computer's display capabilities the DisplayLink Manager App emulates graphics hardware, emulated hardware has reduced hardware acceleration features, as well as some limited functionality including color calibration and Night Shift in macOS.
 
DisplayLink is aware of this limitation and has been working to improve Night Shift and color calibration with their software, however at this time there is no update on if or when this will become available to the DisplayLink controlled displays._

Answer (score 0):

I have an ALOGIC Docking station which uses the DisplayLink Manager application. I was also facing the same issue then found an option to enable it from the DisplayLink Manager settings (Check the image below).

I know you might have tried your settings. Can you try downloading [DisplayLink Manager](https://www.synaptics.com/products/displaylink-graphics/downloads/macos) it provides settings for f.lux out of the box.
[image: DisplayLink Manager settings]

Answer (score -1):

I have a Dell D6000 docking station and had the same issue.
Got it working after I did the following:

1. Quit the Displaylink Manager application and set it so that it does not start on startup.
2. Unplug the Dock connection to your Macbook.
3. Replug the Dock connection to your Macbook.

The monitors should work AND with Night Shift without needing to have the DisplayLink manager running in the background.