# Does macOS allow users to specify which monitor to enable Night Shift if a external monitor is connected?

Tags: macos, display, night-shift

Does macOS allow users to specify which monitor to enable Night Shift if a external monitor is connected? Night Shift is enabled on both monitors when I turn it on.

(I have the latest macOS.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. macOS Monterey and lower treat all color spaces / displays the same for Night Shift and Dark Mode.

- https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/change-displays-night-shift-preferences-mchl9d976e85/mac

Only color calibration profiles apply on a per display basis.

- https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/calibrate-your-display-mchlp1109/mac

Others have had [problems getting externals to shift in the past](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/344649/5472), so perhaps there’s an undocumented manner to break things by [manipulating EDID  or other third party app](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/410933/5472) for your needs.